# Adding methods to scipy.stats.rv_continuous, problems with rv_frozen

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I would like to add a method to all of the distribution in scipy.stats.rv_continuous.  The method would return the cumulative counts, ie the product of an extra parameter nu (the total counts), and the existing cdf function.  I tried adding the new method to the `rv_continuous` class as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous, uniform, gamma

def cntsCumul(self, x, nu): return nu * self.cdf(x)

rv_continuous.cntsCumul = cntsCumul

x = [-0.76, 1.2, 5.67]

for xx in x: print(uniform.cdf(xx)) # OK
for xx in x: print(uniform.cntsCumul(xx, 3)) # Not OK
    
rv1 = uniform()    
for xx in x: print(rv1.cdf(xx)) # OK
for xx in x: print(rv1.cntsCumul(xx, 3)) # Not OK
    
a = 2

for xx in x: print(gamma.cdf(xx, a)) # OK
for xx in x: print(gamma.cntsCumul(xx, a, 3)) # OK

rv2 = gamma(a)
for xx in x: print(rv2.cdf(xx)) # OK
for xx in x: print(rv2.cntsCumul(xx, 3)) # Not OK
```

but get the following error:

```
---> 14 for xx in x: print(rv1.cntsCumul(xx, 3)) # Not OK
     15 
     16 a = 2

AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute 'cntsCumul'
```

Not sure how to deal with `rv_frozen`.  Any suggestions?  Also, not sure if parameters will cause problems.

Comment: Just subclass rv_continous, don't monkey-patch it

Comment: @ev-br if I subclass rv_continuous, how would the change get propagated to all of the distributions that inherit from rv_continuous?

Comment: Frankly, you're doing something really weird here, trying to patch up all of scipy.stats distributions including various subclasses. Missed this point in the original post --- I simply cannot imagine a legit use case

Comment: I am doing likelihood fits with various distributions - I don't know the right one in advance, and the model requires combinations of several distributions.  The method requires the cumulative counts.  Things would be a lot simpler with such a method.   In addition, plotting results would be a lot simpler with a method showing count density.  Not sure what "weird" means in python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue you're seeing is that `rv2.cntsCumul(xx, 3)` creates a so-called frozen distribution, which has shapes and loc/scale fixed --- this way, e.g. `norm(loc=0, scale=2).pdf(x)` is equivalent to `norm.pdf(x, loc=0, scale=2)` etc. In the source code, see `rv_continuous.__call__` etc.
Now, a frozen distribution (an `rv_frozen` instance) creates a fresh instance of the underlying `rv_continuous` subclass (which is stored as a `self.dist` attribute of an `rv_frozen` instance), and that one does not know about your monkey-patching.

Note also that what you are doing does not account for the shape parameters: e.g. `gamma` has shape `a`, so that the signature is `scipy.stats.gamma.pdf(x, a, loc, scale)`. loc and scale have default values, but shapes do not.

On a side note, like I said in the comments, what you're doing is, to put it mildly, somewhat non-standard.
And certainly very error-prone.
If you need several distributions, just subclass their `_gen` classes or monkey-patch the instances if you really must.

Comment: Fair enough.  Am going to start a new thread to hear what the recommended method is.